# GCM Push Notifications being Acknowledged in GCM Diagnostics but return NotRegistered upon Push

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have an Android app that can receive push notifications. It works with my emulator as well as my personal Nexus 5 phone. A customer is no longer receiving push notifications. When I push to their registration token which they had just registered within 5 minutes, the server responds with:

```
{"multicast_id":6888881773609253298,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"}]}
```

In the GCM Diagnostics panel in the Play Developer Console it states that the push notification was acknowledged.

[image: push notification acknowledged]

How can that be?

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

<permission
    android:name="com.my.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.my.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>

<!-- Services -->

<service
    android:name=".pushNotifications.InstanceIdListenerService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<service
    android:name=".pushNotifications.MyAppGcmListenerService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<!-- End Services -->

<receiver
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>

        <category android:name="com.my.app"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

### How the token is retrieved:

```
try
{
    String token = InstanceID.getInstance(_context)
                             .getToken(_context.getString(R.string.push_notification_sender_id),
                                       GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE);

    _preferencesService.setPushNotificationToken(token);

    listener.complete();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    listener.error(e);
    Log.e(_context.getPackageName(), e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: If the http response said that the message failed, how did you match it up in the Android developer console?

Comment: You can input the registration token for the device and it will pull up all the push notification messages sent to that device.

Comment: Agreed I'm just wondering how you knew which one was the one that failed? Did you look at the time?

Comment: Yes, the time. The only other push notification was three hours earlier.

Comment: Has this reproducible? If so can you tell me the device type?

Comment: This has been reproduced in two phones, a Samsung Galaxy S5 and an S6. One is running Android 5.0, the other 5.1. I am curious if it is device specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was not due to GCM. The Client's API was not handling the token's correctly.